# Keeping a reference to one of the values in the hash map

Tags: rust

I have this structure in rust:

```rust
pub struct Wallet {
    default_account: Option<Account>,
    accounts: HashMap<String, Account>,
}
```

`default_account` is going to be either `None` or a reference to one of the `Account` objects in the `accounts` hash map. Is that possible in rust?

Currently, I just create a `clone` of one of the `Account`s and put it back to `default_account`.

Comment: It's possible, but you need to use Rc or Arc.

Comment: I suggest using the following datastructure: `struct Wallet { accounts: Vec<Account>, default_account: Option<usize>, accounts_map: HashMap<String, usize> }`. (The `usize`s are indices into the `accounts` vec).
This case is slightly different than the supposed duplicate, giving more options for a good solution.

Comment: That's almost strictly worse than using `Rc` @ChrisB it only improves `Account` mutation ergonomics a little but has severe issues when you want to remove `Account`s that are not the last in the `Vec`.

Comment: @cafce25: I assumed that the whole point of this question is performance, not ergonomics. Otherwise the `clone` would be just fine. A `swap_remove` from the `Vec` plus a single index fixup in the hashmap are not too bad if deletions are not the common case. Heap allocating (-> cache missing) every single account might be much worse. But I agree that it depends on the usecase.

Comment: @ChrisB What worries me about `clone` is not performance (although that too could be an issue depending on how `Account` is defined), but redundancy. Redundancy introduces unpleasant complexity as the code base grows.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, the Rc/Arc variant could look like this: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=081bf19d8dd3ce65f8ebc4aabdc4a517

Comment: @user4815162342: Depending on the usecase (does the default Account ever get mutated?) I totally agree that the `Rc` version might be more maintainable. You might also be right that that is what OP was after, I just happened to interpret it from a performance perspective. We might never know because somebody decided to dupe hammer this immediately without asking questions.